# pyodbc import error: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm very new to python and all it's wonders and I'm trying to get something someone else wrote to work.   Unfortunately, that someone else is no longer available here so I can't go to him in person.  I'm now just trying to get the import portion of his code to work and it won't import pyodbc.

I downloaded and ran the installer named pyodbc-3.0.7.win32-py2.7.exe.  It dropped some files into my C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages directory.  I then added C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages to my pythonpath environment variable.    I checked that it's there by importing sys and print sys.path and got the below

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I then type import pyodbc and get the below

```
 >>> import pyodbc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
     import pyodbc
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I opened up the Path Browser and I was able to find pyodbc.pyd.

Comment: That is usually a error message when trying to import 32bit modules with 64bit python.

Comment: How can I tell if I have 64bit or 32bit python?  I did the below bit of code and got win32.>>> import sys
>>> print sys.platform
win32
>>>

Comment: It's usually contained in the output of this. `print sys.version`

Comment: Well what do you know.   I'm running the 64 bit version of python.   Thank you for your help.  2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: M4rtini, you should put that as an answer so he can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably happens when you try to import 32 bit libraries on 64 bit python or vice-verso.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `pyodbc` which is suitable with your 64-bit/32-bit Python. You can download the unofficial wheel here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc